# Welcome Mails based on user role

Tags: functions, user-roles, email

hope you can help me. users can chose between subscriber and editor role on my website. now, i'd like to send a register welcome mail to EDITORS only (WITH a specific) text. subscribers must not receive a welcome mail.

any chance?

looking forward hearing from you! THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

ah, there is a plugin that does this, but it also have some more features.

[Check here (plugin - WelcomeUser!)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/welcomeuser/)

Comment: It has nothing to do with welcome email.

Answer (score 0):

add to your functions.php file:

```
add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification', 'my_if_notification_required');

function my_if_notification_required( $user ){
    $user = get_userdatabylogin( $user );
    if( $user && in_array('editor', $user->roles) ) return true;
    else return false;
}

add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'my_notification_text');

function my_notification_text( $user, $user_email, $key, $meta ){
    $user = get_userdatabylogin( $user );
    if( !$user || !in_array('editor', $user->roles) ) return false;
    $message = 'Your message';
    return $message;
}
```